# can I substitute "an art form" for any other alternatives in this cases?

Tags: word-usage

When I constructed a sentence, "Peking opera is an art form". I realized I had multiple options. And then I tried to distinguish the difference between "an art form" and "a form of art".

I googled it and I got [a post](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/art-form-or-form-of-art.997193/), which says

> "Art form" is really a fixed phrase, almost jargon, that means "a form of art", "a type of art", "a style of art".

Which means "art form" is the most common phrase and is justified by [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+form+of+art%2Ca+type+of+art%2Ca+genre+of+art%2C+an+art+form&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008).

[image]

So, I can substitute "an art form" for any other alternatives in any cases.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You are assuming that all those phrases have exactly the same meaning. That is the danger in using ngram. What **exact** meaning are you trying to convey? Only after that is known will you have a question to which a meaningful answer can be given.

Comment: @JeffMorrow  Thanks to your reminder, I updated it. That’s very kind of you.

Comment: I agree that, in the context given, all the phrases are equally acceptable and virtually equivalent.. But **none** says even as much as "Peking opera is a type of opera" rather than afternoon TV. I suspect that you intend to say that "Peking opera" is serious musical theater, not pop culture. It may well be you intend to say even more. But "art form" may cover literature, music, the visual arts, serious art or superficial art. It has such a broad field of meaning that it conveys very little. Of course, your alternatives do not convey much of anything either. What do you **really** want to say?

Comment: @JeffMorrow You are right. As an example of "art form", I should have said "Opera is an art form."

Comment: @JeffMorrow You got me! That's not what I originally did.  Actually, I constructed a sentence, "peking opera was one of the most popular form a entertainment and art 100 years ago" but I’m not sure whether it is natural. So I broke it down into parts and checked them separately with Ngram Viewer.