# Is it reasonable to say the pattern `noun + be + adj` is incomplete?

Tags: grammar

I wrote the following sentence in [a post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/251710/116345)

> "art form" is the most common phrase.

In fact, I constructed it as the following version first and then changed it as the one above.

> "art form" is the most common.

The abandoned version doesn't have the noun "phrase" at the end of it.

A native speaker told me that it was incomplete but she didn't explain why is that.

I seems that the pattern `noun + be + adj` is incomplete, which might not be true in general.

Is it because the sentence uses the superlative form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on context.

The direct object may be understood, e.g.

Question: `"What phrase is the most common in the corpus?"`

Answer: `"art form" is the most common.`

That is common colloquialusage. The 'A' of the first word probably should be capitalized, but one could argue "e e cummings is a poet" is correct to maintain the case as given.

Without the question, though, I would not consider it a complete thought nor sentence. The sentence, `"Art form" is the most common phrase,` is valid. To improve it, if it stands alone, then you might state *where* that phrase is found so often.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent example. How about my first quotation, *"art form" is the most common phrase*? Could it be considered complete on its own?

Comment: Yes, and I'll amend the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Does this version, *'Ngram Viewer shows "art form" is the most common phrase'*, answer the question where that phrase is found so often?

Comment: Yes, it could be a correct answer.